# VBA Dynamic HTML body in mail

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I'm creating some mail templates using VBA. The idea is to have all the templates in an Excel document, where everyone can easily change it and add more templates. These people wont have access to the VBA code, so everything is read from here.

I want to do it as an HTML body, to include the signature and format the text, and this is where the problem arise.

This code works just fine, and this is the layout I want to recreate:

```
Sub Stackoverflow1()
Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set objOutlookMsg = objOutlook.CreateItem(olMailItem)
With objOutlookMsg
    .To = "Dennis@Stackoverflow.com"
    .Subject = "MAIL TEST"
    .Display
    .HTMLBody = "<p style='font-family:arial;font-size:13'>" & _
    "Hi" & "<br>" & "<br>" & _
    "TEST TEST TEST TEST" & _
    .HTMLBody
    .Display
End With
End Sub
```

cell(2,1) is the following string:

```
"Hi" & "<br>" & "<br>" & "TEST TEST TEST TEST" &
```

Where I'm trying to input it into the outlook mail as the following:

```
Sub Stackoverflow2()
StrTEST = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(2, 1)                              '<----------------

Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set objOutlookMsg = objOutlook.CreateItem(olMailItem)
With objOutlookMsg
    .To = "Dennis@Stackoverflow.com"
    .Subject = "MAIL TEST"
    .Display
    .HTMLBody = "<p style='font-family:arial;font-size:13'>" & _
     StrTEST _                                                         '<----------------
    .HTMLBody 
    .Display
End With
End Sub
```

Even though the "text" is technically the same it obviously dont work, and I get an object required error. Does anyone know how to make the above work and not read it as string?

Comment: Why are you setting `.HTMLBody` to `....strTest.... .HTMLBody`? Isn't the second `.HTMLBody` just an empty string is it set elsewhere?

Comment: Also change `StrTEST _` to `StrTEST`

Comment: The problem is that you're missing the `& ` that connects `StrTEST` with `.HTMLBody`. Compare the first code that works with the second, that's not working. `StrTEST &  .HTMLBody`  <-- Just move them together like that

Comment: @Tom if you don't include the last .HTMLBody the signature is not included in the mail.

Comment: @DennisChristiansen Ah makes sense

Comment: @SiddharthRout the _ is used to indicate the line shift? The actual string from the cell includes the &. But changing it to    StrTEST & _ makes no difference.

Comment: @DennisChristiansen the `& _` is to concatenate the string in `VBA` syntax. If it is in the cell it will be just read as part of the string

Comment: @CindyMeister I tried added all of it in one line to the following: ".HTMLBody = "<p style='font-family:arial;font-size:13'>" & StrTEST & .HTMLBody" but I still get an error 91.

Comment: @Tom I tried changing it (see the EDIT), but it dosen't work.

Comment: @DennisChristiansen your edit is still missing the `&` should be: `.HTMLBody = "<p style='font-family:arial;font-size:13'>" & StrTEST & .HTMLBody`

Comment: @tom Thank you! I moved some things around and added the & and it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it to work, by moving the & from the string, in the cell, to the actual code and moving some of it around. For the string, remove the " and simply include < br > (without space) for a lineshift.

```
Cell(2,1) = Hi <br> <br> TEST TEST TEST TEST

Sub Stackoverflow3()
StrTEST = Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(2, 1)

Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set objOutlookMsg = objOutlook.CreateItem(olMailItem)
With objOutlookMsg
    .To = "Dennis@Stackoverflow.com"
    .Subject = "MAIL TEST"
    .Display
    .HTMLBody = "<p style='font-family:arial;font-size:13'>" & StrTEST & .HTMLBody
    .Display
End With
End Sub
```